# Changing Unicode Wide Characters to ASCII

Tags: java, regex, unicode

I am working with text that comes from a variety of different countries and thus languages. There is an amount of text that uses "wide" format characters. They superficially look like standard ASCII characters but have a bit of a different typeface and have extra space around them.

Currently, I loop through every character in the character array representation of the string, test whether the character is in the wide character range, and if so replace the character with its ASCII equivalent and then convert back to a string.

```
public static String wideToShortChars(String s) {
    char[] messagechars = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < messagechars.length; i++) {
        int thisChar = (int) messagechars[i];
        if (thisChar >= 65280 && thisChar <= 65519) {
            messagechars[i] = (char) (thisChar - 65248);
        }
    }
    return new String(messagechars);
}
```

This seems like it would be slow, and I imagine it would be faster to use a RegEx. I have found that I can search for these characters using the `\p{InHalfwidth_and_Fullwidth_Forms}` term in a regex.

Can I construct a RegEx that searches for these wide characters and replaces them with their ASCII/standard equivalents? I only want to do this with letters, numbers and the usual punctuation mark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This seems like it would be slow, and I imagine it would be faster to use a RegEx.

You'd be imagining wrongly I think.  A well written, hand-code search/replace transformation is likely to be faster than the equivalent implemented as a regex.  Besides, I don't think it is possible to do this transformation with a single regex.